# How to set Xamarin iOS navigation and status bar color

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin iOS Designer and am trying to set the status bar and navigation controller background color as shown in this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DApI7aWGNiY

I've opened my main storyboard in Xcode Interface Builder and followed the steps in the tutorial, adding code to appDelegate.m. Code is as follows:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >>    16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary   *)launchOptions
{

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x067AB5)];

return YES;
}

@end
```

The above doesn't seem to work - the status and navigation bar remain gray when I save and build in Xamarin.

I'm wondering why and if it has anything to do with the fact that the project was created in Xamarin and not Xcode. My .m file resides in a "supporting files" folder unlike the demo and it doesn't contain any of the auto-generated code. There seems to be much better documentation on Xcode Interface Builder which is why I have been using that instead of the newer Xamarin iOS Designer.

Xamarin Studio 5.1.3 and Xcode 5.1.1
Any tips? Thanks!

**Update: Was able to achieve the background color change on both status and nav bar by adding 
    this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Yellow;
to my viewcontroller.cs right after `base.ViewDidLoad ();`. Would still like to know why code added to the Xcode project .m files does not render in the Xamarin build.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to change the navigation bar color throughout your entire iOS app add this to your AppDelegate FinishedLaunching method:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.YourColor;
```

You can also edit the text attributes for the navigation bar by doing the following:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes { TextColor = UIColor.White });
```

As for the status bar if you want to change the status bar icons to white instead of default black, for example, create a class for your navigation controller and override UIStatusBarStyle

```
public override UIStatusBarStyle PreferredStatusBarStyle ()
{
     return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
}
```

This would work for your NavigationController and any child controllers of it.

Comment: On second thought if you do change it that way you might want to do UINavigationBar.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(type); just so you don't change some of iOS 7s default styles for popups and things

Answer (score 7):

I finally got this working in Xamarin Forms so blogged about it, see http://morganskinner.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/xamarin-forms-light-status-bar-for-ios.html for full details. I also have a follow up post on setting a background image for the Navigation bar and have it working for Landscape too - see http://morganskinner.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/xamarin-formsusing-background-images-on.html. Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Thanks adding UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to the plist source and setting it to No is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The below line code may be helpful for you.

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated){

    NavigationController.NavigationBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0)
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
         @{
           UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor clearColor],UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)],UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:18.0f]
           }];
        CGFloat verticalOffset = 0;
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:verticalOffset forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        // Uncomment to change the color of back button
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        // Uncomment to assign a custom backgroung image
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        // Uncomment to change the back indicator image

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];

        // Uncomment to change the font style of the title

        NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
        shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
        shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:18.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

        CGFloat verticalOffset = 0;
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:verticalOffset forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
```